# html colspan issue when hiding columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table that has two 2 sets of headers, major headers which each will have 5 subheaders. The goal is to only show 3 columns and correctly allow the user to sort based on the major headers.

Out of the these five subheaders, columns 4 and 5 will always be visible, but for the first 3 columns I only want to show one the user selects, and hide the other two. Ulitmately head major header will only show 3 columns.

When the user selects which of the data to show, issues arise with the column headers.

If I set the major headers to colspan 5 then columns from the next set overflow into the first set, given an incorrect appearance

When I set the major headers colspan to 3, visibly it looks perfect, however when I try sorting based on major headers, subheaders are not matched to their major headers and sorting is off.

here is a fiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/hed56hsd/1/

What am I missing? and What would be a valid workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only three columns of each set will be visible, the simplest solution would be to set the `colspan` on the major header to `3`. That's it.

```
<th colspan='3' class="set1">Set 1</th>
<th colspan='3' class="set2">Set 2</th>
<th colspan='3' class="set3">Set 3</th>
```

On initialization, you can apply the data selector by adding `.change()` at the end of the event listener - [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hed56hsd/4/).

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  theme: 'blue'
});

$(".selector").on("change", function() {
  var selectedData = this.value;
  $(".type1").addClass("hide");
  $('.' + selectedData).removeClass("hide");
}).change();
```

If it was any more complicated than that I would have recommended you try out the [columnSelector widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) which automatically modifies the `colspan` to keep the table format from messing up.